# Calculating the determinant of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A \in M_n(k)$ such that $A^3-A^2 + A - I_n =0$

1.) Prove that $A$ is invertible and determine $A^{-1}$

2.) Calculate $det(A)$

For the first question :

$A^3-A^2 + A - I_n =0$

$A(A^2-A + I_n) =I_n$

Hence $A^{-1}$ = $(A^2-A + I_n)$

For the 2nd question :

Assume that $x^3-x^2 + x - 1 $ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ .

which has 1 real root $x = 1$ which is the eigenvalue.

since the determinant is equal to the product of eigenvalues $det(A)=1$

However I'm not sure if my assumption is correct nor if i should prove that A is diagonalizable for the determinant to be equal to the product of the eigenvalues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is known about the field $k$?

Comment: There are several possibilities for the determinant. Since $p(x)=x^3-x^2+x-1=(x-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x+i)(x-i)$ vanishes at $A$, then $A$ can have eigenvalues $1,\pm i$. If $\pm i\notin k$, then either $A=I$ or the eigenvalues $\pm i$ appear in conjugate pairs in the characteristic polynomial. In which case the determinant is $1$. But if $\pm i\in k$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ could be any subset of $\{1,\pm i\}$ with any multiplicity (Look at diagonal matrices with these numbers in the diagonal). Therefore the determinant could be any products that you can form with these numbers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Nothing is known about the field $k$ , so i guess I should take 2 cases as totoro said.